# Equivalent of form_open_multipart of CodeIgniter in HTML

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have a form for uploading files; now it is in PHP CodeIgniter; but I have to change it in an ajax call and show it with appending to an empty div in my code by .html attribute of my empty tag.

My current CodeIgniter code for form is as following:

```
            <?php
            $formData = array(
                'class' => 'form-horizontal',
            );
            echo form_open_multipart('bulletin', $formData);
            ?>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <?PHP
                    $uderFileData = array(
                        'id' => 'userfile',
                        'name' => 'userfile',
                        'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
                        'required' => 'true',
                    );
                    echo form_upload($uderFileData);
                    echo form_close();
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I don't know how I can pass the same structure in HTML format; in other forms I dont know what is the equivalent of "form_open_multipart " in HTML! Could you please let me know the equivalent.

If my question is not clear, please let me know which part you need more clarification.

Many thanks:)

Comment: Take a look at the source code of your page, you'll the generated HTML.  That will show you what `form_open_multipart` does.

Comment: ummm good idea man...

Comment: @RocketHazmat hey man if you wish you can post your answer as a new answer, so I would be able to accept it as the answer! btw, it was a simple form tag with  enctype='multipart/form-data' thanks you solved my problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`form_open_multipart` just creates a `<form>` tag with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, this is needed for file uploads.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="bulletin">
```